# Where is the backup application log for SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, logging, backup

I need to check out why a database backup failed in one of our systems.

The log says the following:

> BACKUP failed to complete the command BACKUP LOG XXXXXX. Check the
>   backup application log for detailed messages.

I went into Windows event logs , checked the application logs, and guess what I have found for this specific error in those logs

> BACKUP failed to complete the command BACKUP LOG XXXXXX. Check the
>   backup application log for detailed messages.

Where is the actual backup application log stored at by default?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

open SSMS  and connect to the database
go to MANAGEMENT > MAINTENANCE PLAN > pick your backup plan. > right click and view history.

or to MANAGEMENT > sql server logs.

directory location : `c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.xx\MSSQL\LOG`

Comment: You earned this one! way to go!  ... Dammit, been doing .NET development for nearly 3 years now, and still too much to learn.

Comment: cheers mate! everyday learning as they say... what's wrong with your backup?

Comment: nothing serious. someone attempted a DDL statement on the database as the backup attempted to run, causing it to stop unexpectedly. All that was needed was to re-run the backup.

Comment: I'm having difficulty with this answer. I'm performing a backup using PowerShell.  The backup fails. Looking at the Maintenance Plans doesn't work since this isn't a plan. Going to Management > Sql Server logs displays the same error message. Going to the MSSQL.xx\MSSQL\Log and looking at that log shows the exact same message as whats in SQL Server Log.  Where is this backup application log which shows the detailed message?

Comment: @GeoffDawdy, I suspect by "application" log, they mean that SQL Server throws the message to the calling application and assumes it is their responsibility to log it.   For calling backups via an SP,  this seems to mean the message is just lost.  Even xp_readerrorlog does not include the same failure messages as those shown from within the MaintenancePlan (i.e.the Application) logs.

Comment: I had the same problem. Any ideas how to drill any further than this?

Comment: This doesn't quite answer the specific question. We are looking at the logs in the locations you have specified and that is the message found.

Comment: same issue as @GeoffDawdy Errorlog shows the same message to check the application log...

Answer (score 9):

The only information that SQL server itself captures is what you've already quoted:

> BACKUP failed to complete the command XXXXXX. Check the backup application log for detailed messages.

This is all that will show up in the SQL error log (SSMS > Management > SQL Server Logs), and the Windows Application errorlog from MSSQLSERVER.

When it says "check the backup application log", it means *check the log (if there is one) of whatever application actually performed the backup*:

- If the backup ran as part of a SQL agent job, check the job history for that job (not the "SQL agent log").
- If the backup ran as part of a SSIS package, check the SSIS package log, if it was configured to create one.
- If the backup ran as part of a SQL maintenance plan, check the history for that maintenance plan.
- If the backup was run via a 3rd-party backup software, check that application's log.
- If you can't find it anywhere else, check the Windows application event log to see if something else was logged by another application at the same time  "BACKUP failed" was logged by MSSQLSERVER.

If you can't find it anywhere else, the more detailed error may not have been captured. The SSIS package may not have been configured to do detailed logging, or maybe someone ran a manual backup in the GUI but dismissed or fixed the error on-screen. You may have to find out who attempted to run the backup and ask them why it failed.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Backing up the DBs with a PS.Script. The information in the log was not helpful. The cause was a **timeout** of my powershell script.

A setting of "$server.ConnectionContext.StatementTimeout = 0" was not helping

$ret=Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $SQLStatement -ServerInstance $ServerName -ErrorAction 'Stop' **-QueryTimeOut 600**

Setting the QueryTimeOut was doing the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Dear this error normally occur if you dont have full backup.... with some reasons if the full backup schedule didnt complete it will give this error

What you can do is either execute the full backup plan or wait till the full backup job complete successfully then automatically it will start taking hourly backups