# Running a SQL server backup using IIS and PHP PDO

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I have been working on this for a while with no success.  Here is what I am currently trying but I have tried a ton of different things as well.  Has anyone ever successfully done this or is it a limitation of PDO with SQL server?

```
 $disk = "d:\backup\testBackup.bak";
 $foo = $db->exec("BACKUP MyDb TO DISK'".$location."'");
```

AND stored procedure

```
 $foo = $db->exec("webBackup");
```

Both seem to be working on the backup but fail in the end.  I can see in the SQL performance monitor that it seems to be doing the backup but at some point, it just stops.

No errors returned or in the php log, but I get 3 errors in the SQL log:

Source: Backup - BACKUP failed to complete the command BACKUP DATABASE PWNT. Check the backup application log for detailed messages.

Source: Backup - Error: 3041, Severity: 16, State: 1.

Source: MSSQLSERVER - BACKUP failed to complete the command BACKUP DATABASE PWNT. Check the backup application log for detailed messages.

I have looked at permissions issues and have also turned up any timeout setting I can find.  The backup takes about 3 minutes when run.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531563/where-is-the-backup-application-log-for-sql-server-2008) help?

Comment: Unfortunately, I've been through that thread and the logs it directs me to are the SQL logs the errors above are coming from.  I think the "backup application log" the application is MY application and I am getting no errors within my app or returned to it when I attempt to run a backup.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue today, albeit using Laravel's `Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB`.

Using `DB::statement(<query>)` I had the same issue as you, but using `DB::select(DB::raw(<query>)` it works (it just throws a tiny exception but that's OK).

In your case, could that be the difference between using `$db->exec(<query>)` and `$db->query(<query>)`? Counter-intuitive, I know.