# Where is 'Management' in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server

Our server is throwing an error during one of the backup routines. I found a potential solution on another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531563/where-is-the-backup-application-log-for-sql-server-2008) but I can't find where 'Management' is. Imagine my frustration at trying to google SSMS Management location.

Comment: Could be it is not installed on the server where the sql server instance is running. Typically MS recommends you execute commands against a production instance from a different PC *other* than the server where the instance is being hosted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Management in SSMS is a category nested under each connected server in the object explorer. If you expand a Server in the (usually) left-hand pane object-explorer, you should see the management folder listed.

[image]